# Incorrect revision diff for lists

Tags: bug, diff, list

In the [second revision](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/11571/revisions) of my post I've added two links as list items and removed a sentence. The Markdown diff looks fine:

> [image: Markdown diff]

But the inline and two-column mode diffs look weird:

> [image: Two-column-mode diff]

The first eight list items are not changed, but marked as different in these modes.

Here is one more ugly situation: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1268/revisions (Revision 69). It looks like the ENTIRE post was modified, but it wasn't. Compare with Markdown mode.

Comment: This is very common when making formatting changes, especially in lists. Isn't there a duplicate here (that is, asked about many times over here at MSE)?